# Why do we only include core electrons in Larmor diamagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

In the Larmor diamagnetism derivation of a susceptibility $\chi = -\mu_0 \frac{\rho e^2}{6m} <r^2>$, we are told to use the density of *core* electrons as $\mu$ and not all of the electrons in the atom. Why is this?

I understand that the valence electrons will contribute more to the paramagnetic effect, but why not also include their contribution to a weaker diamagnetic effect in this calculation (unless for some reason they do not contribute)?